# Are Non blittable structs treated as reference type?

Tags: c#, marshalling, low-level

If I have a non blittable struct, how it is treated by the compiler/CLR?

For example: if I have a non blittable struct X which I pass **without** the 'ref/out' keyword to some method, what actually will be passed to this method? A pointer to the actual allocated struct on the managed heap or the compiler will make a copy of the struct's instance onto the stack when passing to the method?

Thanks.

Comment: It makes a copy.  If you need any modifications made to the struct to be copied back then you have to use [Out].

Comment: Hi @HansPassant. The problem is that I'm using async methods, and they appear to not accept as parameter: pointers, ref and out. I'm reading about this "limitation" and a workaround I found is to use the class Tuple to hold the references to be passed to the async method. Do you know if this workaround have any downside? Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be a struct? Can you use a class in the first place?

Comment: Hello @argaz. Yes, it have to be struct, I make some heavy use of Marshal and for this I just can't use classes. What downsides you know for using Tuple? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Blittable` and `Non-Blittable` types are only relevant in the context of marshaling.
When passing `structs` to managed methods, the regular rules of `value types` apply, meaning a copy is made.

In case you want to wrap your original `struct`, which is what you want judging from your comments, the option you discussed is to use a `Tuple`, the only downside I see from this is readability: `Tuple.Item1/Item2` may be unclear.

Another option is to make a wrapper class that would contain your `struct` as its only property:

```
class StructWrapper
{
     YourStruct Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If the only downside of using Tuple is readability it's very chap for me, I can deal with this. I was worried about some more dangerous downsides as in performance, scalability, etc.